# Move database from local datastore to another local datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt

I and my friend are working on a GWT-Google App Engine project, using Tortoise SVN and Google Code to synchronize the code. 
We also synchronize the local_db.bin file in appengine-generated folder. But we cant get it work. After synchronize the db file, our local datastore is not updated as we expected. 
That is a pain. Im worrying about our future, when our database get bigger and more complicated @A@.
Anyone please give me an advice. What should i do to synchronize our local datastore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to suggestions:
1) Use remote api : https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/remote_api to share a GAE hosted db locally.
2) Maybe you can use Gdrive to sync folders.

Answer (score 1):

This is a really bad idea. Even if you weren't having trouble making both ends read from the same datastore file, the local datastore is in a binary format, and thus you won't both be able to work on the app at the same time, or you'll get merge conflicts you will be unable to resolve.

Instead, both for collaboration purposes and for testing and deployment, you should provide a set of test data you can easily load into the datastore. Store the test data in version control, and load it in using bulkloader or your own code.